# Add Link to New SharePoint Files using Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

In it's simplest form what I'm trying to do is use power automate to update an excel spreadsheet every time I upload a file to SharePoint. The main issue is one of the categories I'd like to add is a direct link to the SharePoint PDF file I upload. But for every reference I've looked up it tells me to use the SharePoint ID code but I just don't have it.

Here's an example to a reference: [How to find the IDs of the items in a Flow so I can update the correct items?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277838/how-to-find-the-ids-of-the-items-in-a-flow-so-i-can-update-the-correct-items)

Any idea why and how to get it to work? I've attached a photo below showing what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Después del desencadenador podrías establecer una variable con el ID del documento creado con las opciones que resalto en Amarillo, u luego usar la variable donde lo requieras

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. It gives a link like below but I want an actual hyper link.  For example: -----What it gives: 252f11596%2b-%2bInvoice%2b-%2b28th%2bStreet.pdf----What I want: https://(SharePoint ).com/:b:/s/BillTracking/EYpIvNLDv8BJqvAkRF